# Why arent my sprite images showing up?

Tags: html, css

I need a new pair of eyes on this code. Must have coder's blindness or something. For the life of me I can't figure out why the images aren't loading up on page.

I've been sitting here comparing this to other working code with different classes and image sprite and can't see where the issue is.

If someone wouldn't mind taking a minute or two and running over it I'd appreciate it a lot.

```
.480sl1, .480sl2, .480sl3, .480sl4, .480sl5, .480sl6, .480sl7, .480sl8, .480sl9, .480sl10, .480sl11, .480sl12, .480sl13
{background-image: url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/480-sl-sprite.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:166px;   
display:inline-block;



}



.480sl1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.480sl2 {background-position: 0px -166px;}
.480sl3 {background-position: 0px -332px;}
.480sl4 {background-position: 0px -498px;}
.480sl5 {background-position: 0px -664px;}
.480sl6 {background-position: 0px -830px;}
.480sl7 {background-position: 0px -996px;}
.480sl8 {background-position: 0px -1162px;}
.480sl9 {background-position: 0px -1328px;}
.480sl10 {background-position: 0px -1494px;}
.480sl11 {background-position: 0px -1660px;}
.480sl12 {background-position: 0px -1826px;}
.480sl13 {background-position: 0px -1992px;}
```

```
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-mobile-wallpapers.htm"><img class="480sl1"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480-x-800-mobile-wallpaper.htm"><img class="480sl2"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cellphone-wallpapers.htm"><img class="480sl3"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480-x-800-cellphone-wallpaper.htm"><img class="480sl4"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cell-phone-wallpapers.htm"><img class="480sl5"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-cell-phone-480-x-800-wallpaper.htm"><img class="480sl6"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-mobile-backgrounds.htm"><img class="480sl7"></img></a></div><div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-mobile-480-x-800-background.htm"><img class="480sl8"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cellphone-backgrounds.htm"><img class="480sl9"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-cellphone-480-x-800-background.htm"><img class="480sl10"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cell-phone-backgrounds.htm"><img class="480sl11"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-cell-phone-480-x-800-background.htm"><img class="480sl12"></img></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="samsung-galaxy-s-2-ii-i9100-480x800-mobile-wallpapers.htm"><img class="480sl13"></img></a></div>
```

Comment: Can't say anything without knowing more details.

Comment: Can u please clarify your question by more specific    ??

Comment: Are there any error in the developer console in the browser? Also, is there a reason you are using background images and not the src attribute? The answer on this question suggests a way of deciding when to use img or a background image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288500/img-vs-background-image-css-in-performance

Comment: Down voters want to explain to the class why they down voted my question seeing that my question was solved very quickly by some one that DID understand the question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but since you ask: Your question fits two out of three criterias for downvotes: It does not show any research effort and it is not helpful (to others, only to yourself). You could reword the question to make it more useful or at least findable by asking, for example, "Why aren't my CSS sprites visible" instead of "Another pair of eyes on my code".

Comment: @geral schneider Do explain a research effort example for this situation please.

Answer (score 5):

One simple reason: **your CSS / HTML classes can't start with numbers!**

I changed your class names and the image immediately popped up. That's the only thing you need(ed) to do.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-mobile-wallpapers.htm"><img class="aClassNameStartingWithaLetter"></img></a></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.aClassNameStartingWithaLetter {
background-image: url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/480-sl-sprite.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:166px;   
display:inline-block;
}

.aClassNameStartingWithaLetter {background-position: 0px 0px;}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uo5cah4g/1/**

Comment: Well there you go then. Thanks for that.

Comment: No problemo. You won't forget this one now :) PS: accept the answer if it helped you so that we can remark it as solved.

Comment: No i wont forget that

Comment: Your CSS / HTML classes can't start with numbers! ... (I cant catch this) +1

Answer (score 0):

> Your **`class name`** is invalid

**Class name rule**

> a name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a
>   letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters,
>   or numbers

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000)

```
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-mobile-wallpapers.htm"><img class="sl1"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480-x-800-mobile-wallpaper.htm"><img class="sl2"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cellphone-wallpapers.htm"><img class="sl3"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480-x-800-cellphone-wallpaper.htm"><img class="sl4"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cell-phone-wallpapers.htm"><img class="sl5"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-cell-phone-480-x-800-wallpaper.htm"><img class="sl6"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-mobile-backgrounds.htm"><img class="sl7"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-mobile-480-x-800-background.htm"><img class="sl8"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cellphone-backgrounds.htm"><img class="sl9"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-cellphone-480-x-800-background.htm"><img class="sl10"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-480x800-cell-phone-backgrounds.htm"><img class="sl11"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="free-cell-phone-480-x-800-background.htm"><img class="sl12"/></a></div>
<div class="top_grow11"><a href="samsung-galaxy-s-2-ii-i9100-480x800-mobile-wallpapers.htm"><img class="sl13"/></a></div>

.sl1,
.sl2,
.sl3,
.sl4,
.sl5,
.sl6,
.sl7,
.sl8,
.sl9,
.sl10,
.sl11,
.sl12,
.sl13 {
    background-image: url('https://freephonewallpapersformobile.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/-sl-sprite.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 166px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.sl1 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.sl2 {
    background-position: 0px -166px;
}

.sl3 {
    background-position: 0px -332px;
}

.sl4 {
    background-position: 0px -498px;
}

.sl5 {
    background-position: 0px -664px;
}

.sl6 {
    background-position: 0px -830px;
}

.sl7 {
    background-position: 0px -996px;
}

.sl8 {
    background-position: 0px -1162px;
}

.sl9 {
    background-position: 0px -1328px;
}

.sl10 {
    background-position: 0px -1494px;
}

.sl11 {
    background-position: 0px -1660px;
}

.sl12 {
    background-position: 0px -1826px;
}

.sl13 {
    background-position: 0px -1992px;
}
```