# Alt text gets displayed on image

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following `<img>` tag and `css` code:

```css
#image1 
{
        background-image: url("../images/home-page/image1.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="image1" alt="image1" />
```

On my web page image and alt attribute text both get displayed. If image is present then I don't want to display the alt text. Don't know what the problem is. Anyone knows how to solve it? And what is the problem?

Comment: Better explanation here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image and another here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288500/img-vs-background-image-css-in-performance

Comment: Give the image a `src` attribute, and remove the background image …?

Comment: I used different sizes of images for different resolution. If I used `src` then how can i change that image? It always use image given in `src` attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It displays the alt text because the image failed to load. The image failed to load because it doesn't have a `src` attribute.

- If you want a content image, then use a `src` attribute.
- If you want a background image, then don't use an `<img>` element.

> I used different sizes of images for different resolution.

Then you want [the `<picture>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture):

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 650px)"
    srcset="images/kitten-stretching.png">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 465px)"
    srcset="images/kitten-sitting.png">
  <img 
    src="images/kitten-curled.png" 
    alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```

Example via [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/)

Answer (score 1):

> `alt` attribute specifies an alternate text for an image, if the image
>   cannot be displayed.

Here in this scenario `alt` is displayed as `src` is mising.

I could think of 2 solutions.

1. Keep `alt` text blank if you don't wish to see any text.
2. Use a `div` and specify the `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, youn can use the `alt` attribute only with a `src` attribute. Excluding the `src` will always lead the `alt` to get displayed (as it's happening in your example). So in your case, you would do something like that:

```css
#image1 {
    /* This is obsolete, as @Pugazh already mentioned (you better use fix values) */
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<img id="image1" alt="image1" src="../images/home-page/image1.jpg" />
```

You can also see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp8oy55f/).

Comment: While adding `src` to the image, `background-size: 100% 100%;` doesn't mean anything.  You should specify `width` and `height` to control the image size

Comment: You're pretty much right. In this case that's kinda obsolete, yet I only used his shared snippet for demonstrational purpose.