# Slow image loading from the source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple chrome extension and testing out loading of the image for the background. Weird thing is, that I am loading it from the src folder and from what I can see in the network tab, the image loads in 20-50ms

But I always have this strange loading glitching

[image]

This white space above is still not loaded image. Any ideas why its causing it and how I can improve so it loads/renders the whole image instantly?

Comment: Do you possibly have network throttling on in your developer console?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I did for testing but initially when I load the page I dont have the dev console open and this weird image loading happens. Its basically just an index file with an img tag taking the 1mb image and covering all bg

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by simply using `img` tag and not as an element with the background image prop to cover the entire screen. As soon as I implemented using the `img` tag, the issue was solved

Comment: There are some links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288500/img-vs-background-image-css-in-performance) that may be related.